# RoR=> Strange validate message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I'm a newbie in rails, today I made my first web application using the validate, I just put this lines into the model:

```
class ClientWorkout < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_numericality_of :paid_amount
  validates_presence_of :client_name

end
```

This is the view part:

```
<% form_for(@client_workout) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
      etc etc
```

Everything works fine, and the value are stored in the db, in succesful case< if an error occour, instead, this error displays on the view in this strange following manner:

```
{{count}} errors prohibited this {{model}} from being saved

There were problems with the following fields:
{{attribute}} {{message}}
{{attribute}} {{message}}
```

(The example show what's happening when 2 parameters of the form are wrong, but this happen in every case)
It doesen't manage to replace "count, model, attribute and message" with the real value.
Anyone can figure out about what's happenned ?
I use Ror 2.3.8 and rails 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

Rails introduced built-in internationalization back in 2.3.  Your issue is a known bug with some combinations of rails and the i18n gem.  If you have i18n gem version 0.5.0, try downgrading to 0.4.2.  If you're using system gems:

```
sudo gem uninstall i18n
sudo gem install i18n -v 0.4.2
```

If you're using RVM to manage your gems, you don't need the `sudo` command.

Comment: Thank you now it works, but ... I don't manage to install the gem i18 0.4.2, the point is that once I've uninstalled the version 0.5.0, The validate message began to behave in the correct way, but now, I'm without the gem i18n because the version 0.4.2 make just fake install, and for fake install I mean the following:    peppe@ubuntu:~$ sudo gem install i18n -v 0.4.2
Successfully installed i18n-0.4.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for i18n-0.4.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for i18n-0.4.2...
peppe@ubuntu:~$ gem list | grep i18n
peppe@ubuntu:~$

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in changing the i18n version you can do the following
Add the below code in `config/locales/en.ym`

If `en:` is already available copy and paste from ActiveRecord

After that stop the server and start again that should display the error messages properly...

```
en:
  activerecord: 
    errors: 
      full_messages: 
        format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
      messages:
        inclusion: "is not included in the list"
        exclusion: "is reserved"
        invalid: "is invalid"
        confirmation: "doesn't match %{attribute}"
        accepted: "must be accepted"
        empty: "can't be empty"
        blank: "can't be blank"
        too_long: "is too long (maximum is %{count} characters)"
        too_short: "is too short (minimum is %{count} characters)"
        wrong_length: "is the wrong length (should be %{count} characters)"
        not_a_number: "is not a number"
        not_an_integer: "must be an integer"
        greater_than: "must be greater than %{count}"
        greater_than_or_equal_to: "must be greater than or equal to %{count}"
        equal_to: "must be equal to %{count}"
        less_than: "must be less than %{count}"
        less_than_or_equal_to: "must be less than or equal to %{count}"
        other_than: "must be other than %{count}"
        odd: "must be odd"
        even: "must be even"
      template:
        header:
          one:    "1 error prohibited this %{model} from being saved"
          other:  "%{count} errors prohibited this %{model} from being saved
```

Comment: Awesome.  I was just trying to troubleshoot this same issue.  Figured out it was an i18n problem, which I remembered coming across way back when on another project.  But didn't know how to take care of messages that matched your template:header:other in the .yml file you posted.  Super helpful.  Thanks.  And a much better solution than changing gem versions, which may have unintended side effects, even if it fixes this problem.